# Magento nginx rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/index.php"

Tags: php, magento, nginx

I'm new to magento and nginx, and am trying to fix the broken links on a website.

In my error log for nginx I have the following:

2017/09/11 17:09:00 [error] 23457#23457: *15 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/index.php", client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/princess-highway/"

In my default config file for nginx I have the following:

```
# magento specific nginx config for the frontend

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;
  root /var/www/html;

  # check if Load Balancer handled SSL
  set $elb_https "off";
  if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "https") {
    set $elb_https "on";
  }

  add_header X-Whom $hostname;
  client_max_body_size 2m;

  location / {
    index index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
    # testing found online
    # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    expires 30d; ## Assume all files are cachable
  }

  ## block access
  location /app/                { deny all; }
  location /includes/           { deny all; }
  location /lib/                { deny all; }
  location /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
  location /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
  location /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
  location /var/                { deny all; }
  location /downloader/         { deny all; }
  location /errors/             { deny all; }
  location /shell/              { deny all; }

  location ~ rss/catalog/(review|notifystock) {
    deny all;
  }

  ## disable .htaccess and other hidden files
  location  /. {
    return 404;
  }

  ## block API access on non-admin instances
  location /api                 { deny all; }

  ## block rss feeds
  location /rss                 { return 404; }

  ## block test scripts
  location ^~ /dev/             { return 403; }

  ## disable hidden files, git files + composer.json
  location ~ /(\.|\.git|composer.json|composer.lock) {
    return 404;
  }

  ## allow access
  location /var/google/         { allow all; }

  #location /admin {
  #  rewrite ^.* http://localhost/factoryx permanent;
  #}

  #location /factoryx {
  #  rewrite ^.* https://ao-admin.ap-southeast-2.staging.factoryx.io/factoryx permanent;
  #}

  location ~ "^/media/picklists/[a-zA-Z0-9]{32}/$" {
    autoindex on;
    autoindex_localtime on;
  }

  ## Magento uses a common front handler
  location @handler {
    rewrite / /index.php;
  }

  location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires 1y;
    log_not_found off;
  }

  ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
  location ~ .php/ {
    rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
  }

  location ~ .php$ {
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }

    expires        off;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param  HTTPS $elb_https;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
    fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
    include        fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
  }
}
```

I have links like this:
http://localhost/princess-highway/index.php/contacts
The above link will work, however the actual links on the navigation menu will take you here:
http://localhost/princess-highway/contacts
Omitting the index.php from the link, and I will get a 500 bad gateway error.

I'm pretty new to this so let me know if I can provide further information.

Thanks!

Comment: In short what do you want your config to do right now? You want ` http://localhost/princess-highway/contacts` to be translated to ` http://localhost/princess-highway/index.php/contacts` automatically? And is it for this path or few other paths also?

Comment: Yes that would be ideal! It's for a few other paths also.

Comment: Does `http://localhost/princess-highway/index.php/contacts` this work for you directly in browser?

Comment: Yes that link will load fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using answer as comments as I need formatting**

Try adding a location

```
location /princess-highway/ {
   rewrite /princess-highway/(.*) /princess-highway/index.php/$1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tarun. I have a few bugs that I have to sort through before I can try this out. Unfortunately my work day is ending, so I will revisit this on Wednesday.